# How to get files and folders from dropbox using php API

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using below files for dropbox login .

index.php

```
<?php require_once 'Dropbox.class.php';
$dropbox = new Dropbox();
$userArray = $dropbox->get('https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info');  
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dropbox API</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Dropbox API</h1>
<?php 
if($dropbox->hasAccess()){  
$result = json_decode($userArray);
echo '
<h2>User Info</h2>
<ul>    
<li>'.$result->display_name.'</li>
<li>'.$result->email.'</li>
</ul> 
<form action="get.php" method="GET">
<label>File name to get:</label>
<input type="text" name="path"/>
<input type="submit" />
';
}
else{
echo '
<h2>Login</h2>
<a href="'.$dropbox->getAccessURL().'">Login to Dropbox</a>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Using index.php code i can login easily and also i can redirect to same file after authetication.but how can list all the dropbox files and how to upload files to dropbox

get.php

```
<?php 
require_once 'Dropbox.class.php';  
$dropbox = new Dropbox(); //create new dropbox object
$root = 'sandbox'; //set to the root either: 'sandbox' or 'dropbox'
$path = $_GET['path']; //path from the form
//using the GET method
echo 'Contents of: https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/'.$root.'/'.$path.'<br>';
echo $dropbox->get('https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/sandbox/test.txt'); // cUrl GET call from dropbox object
//this code uses the getFile method
echo '<br><br>'; //line space
echo 'Contents of: '.$path.'<br>';
echo $dropbox->getFile($root,'test.txt');// getFile method from Dropbox object
?>
```

Dropbox.class.php

```
<?php
session_start();

/**
 * Dropbox API
 *
 * This is a simple PHP plaintext OAuth 1.0 API for Dropbox
 * 
 * @author Sean Thomas Burke <http://www.seantburke.com/>
 */

class Dropbox
{
    //app variables, be sure to set these to your app settings before continuing.
    //they can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps
    private static $APP_KEY         = 'xxxxxx';
    private static $APP_SECRET      = 'xxxxxx';
    private static $CALLBACK_URL        = 'URL';

    //OAuth 1.0 variables
    private $request_token_url;     //url to dropbox.com to get authorization
    private $oauth_token_secret;        //reponse secret from initial request
    private $oauth_request_token;       //initial response token
    private $oauth_access_token;        //store this in your database
    private $oauth_signature;       //store this in your database, they need to be used in every API call
    private $uid;               //the uid returned as $_GET['uid']

    /**
     * Dropbox() 
     * creates the object and decides based on the $_SESSION whether to request() or processCallBack()
     *
     * @author  Sean Thomas Burke <http://www.seantburke.com/>
     */
    public function __construct()
    {   
        //store session variables from a request()
        //this won't do anything until the processCallBack() method is called after the request()
        $this->oauth_token_secret   = $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'];
        $this->oauth_request_token  = $_SESSION['oauth_request_token'];
        $this->oauth_access_token   = $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'];
        $this->oauth_signature      = $_SESSION['oauth_signature'];
        $this->uid          = $_SESSION['uid'];     

        //if the required variables are not set, then decide whether to make a request or process the $_SESSION
        if(!$this->oauth_signature || !$this->oauth_access_token)
        {
            //if the following are not set, then a request needs to be made
            //the fallback decision should be to request for a new token, and not to process the callback method
            if($_GET['uid'] && $_GET['oauth_token'] && $this->oauth_token_secret && $this->oauth_request_token)
            {
                $this->processCallBack();
            }
            else
            {
                $this->request();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * request() 
     *
     * sends a request to get OAuth request token and secret, builds the request_token_url
     * Step 1: call for request
     * @link https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#request-token
     * @link https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#authorize
     * @author  Sean Thomas Burke <http://www.seantburke.com/>
     */
    private function request()
    {
        // initiate a cURL; if you don't know what curl is, look it up at http://curl.haxx.se/
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        //Dropbox uses plaintext OAuth 1.0; make the header for this request
        $headers = array('Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="'.self::$APP_KEY.'", oauth_signature="'.self::$APP_SECRET.'&"');  
        // set cURL options and execute
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token");  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
        $request_token_response = curl_exec($ch);

        //  parse the returned data which has the format:
        // "oauth_token=<access-token>&oauth_token_secret=<access-token-secret>"
        parse_str($request_token_response, $parsed_request_token);

        //check for any errors
        $json_access = json_decode($request_token_response);
        if($json_access->error)
        {
            echo '<br><br>FATAL ERROR: '.$json_access->error.'<br><br>';
        }

        //set these variables in a $_SESSION variable
        $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']     = $parsed_request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_request_token']    = $parsed_request_token['oauth_token'];

        //also store them in the object (unnecessary, but helps understand concept)
        $this->oauth_token_secret       = $parsed_request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
        $this->oauth_request_token      = $parsed_request_token['oauth_token'];

        //get the request URL; this is where you send the user to authorize your request. Be sure to set the CALLBACK_URL before doing this.
        $this->request_token_url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token='.$parsed_request_token['oauth_token'].'&oauth_callback='.self::$CALLBACK_URL;    

    }

    /**
     * processCallBack() 
     * 
     * call this function when the user returns from the request_token_url at dropbox.com 
     * Step 2: Process Request and get Signature and Access Token
     * @link    https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#request-token
     * @author  Sean Thomas Burke <http://www.seantburke.com>
     */
    private function processCallBack()
    {
        //Now we must process the request 
        //same steps as before, but now the header is modified to include the response variables that were stored in the session
        //notice the signature is a concatenation of the app_secret and the token_secret
        $ch = curl_init();  
        $headers = array('Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="'.self::$APP_KEY.'", oauth_token="'.$this->oauth_request_token.'", oauth_signature="'.self::$APP_SECRET.'&'.$this->oauth_token_secret.'"');  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/access_token");  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  

        //execute and parse
        $access_token_response = curl_exec($ch);  
        parse_str($access_token_response, $parsed_access_token);

        //check for errors
        $json_access = json_decode($access_token_response);
        if($json_access->error)
        {
            echo '<br><br>FATAL ERROR: '.$json_access->error.'<br><br>';
        }

        //it is unnecessary to keep the oauth_token_secret and oauth_request_token at this point
        //clear the $_SESSION
        session_unset();

        //store oauth_access_token and oauth_signature responses in $_SESSION
        //again, oauth_signature is a concatenation of the APP_SECRET and the oauth_token_secret response
        //these 2 variables are what you need to make API requests
        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token']     = $parsed_access_token['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_signature']        = self::$APP_SECRET.'&'.$parsed_access_token['oauth_token_secret']; 

        //dropbox also gives you uid, store it
        $_SESSION['uid']            = $_GET['uid'];

        //also store variables in the object for future reference
        $this->oauth_access_token       = $parsed_access_token['oauth_token'];
        $this->oauth_signature          = self::$APP_SECRET.'&'.$parsed_access_token['oauth_token_secret']; 
        $this->uid              = $_GET['uid'];
    }

    /**
     * get($url)
     *
     * Using the REST api, make a call to a REST URL, and it will return the array
     * Step 3: Make an API call
     *
     * @link    https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api    
     * @author  Sean Thomas Burke <http://www.seantburke.com>
     *
     * @param   $url    REST URL        
     * @return  array   decoded from JSON response
     */
    function get($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        $headers = array('Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="'.self::$APP_KEY.'", oauth_token="'.$this->oauth_access_token.'", oauth_signature="'.$this->oauth_signature.'"');  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $api_response = curl_exec($ch);
        return $api_response;
    }

    /**
     * call($url)
     *
     * Using the REST api, make a call to a REST URL, and it will return the array
     * Step 3: Make an API call
     *
     * @link    https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api    
     * @author  Sean Thomas Burke <http://www.seantburke.com>
     *
     * @param   $url    REST URL        
     * @return  array   decoded from JSON response
     */
    function put($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        $headers = array('Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="'.self::$APP_KEY.'", oauth_token="'.$this->oauth_access_token.'", oauth_signature="'.$this->oauth_signature.'"');  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $api_response = curl_exec($ch);
        return json_decode($api_response);
    }


    /**
     * getAccessURL() 
     * returns the URL used for requests
     * @link    https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#authorize
     * @author  Sean Thomas Burke <http://www.seantburke.com>
     *
     * @return  string of URL for requesting OAuth Token
     */
    function getAccessURL()
    {
        //get the Request URL
        return $this->request_token_url;
    }

    /**
     * hasAccess() 
     * check to see if the user has access already
     *
     * @author  Sean Thomas Burke <http://www.seantburke.com>
     * @return  boolean of 3 required variables (uid is not required, but it helps)
     */
    function hasAccess()
    {
        return ($this->oauth_access_token && $this->oauth_signature && $this->uid);
    }


    /**
     * getFile()
     * get a file from the dropbox
     * @link    https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#files-GET
     * @author  Sean Thomas Burke <http://www.seantburke.com>
     *
     * @param   $root {sandbox, dropbox} $path {url path to document}
     * @return  files contents
     */
    function getFile($root, $path)
    {
        //return $this->get('https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/'.$root.'/'.$path);
        return $this->get('https://api.dropbox.com/1/files/'.$root.'/'.$path);
    }

    /**
     * putFile 
     * get a file from the dropbox
     * @link    https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#files-GET
     * @author  Sean Thomas Burke <http://www.seantburke.com>
     *
     * @param   $root {sandbox, dropbox} $path {url path to document}
     * @return  boolean of 3 required variables (uid is not required, but it helps)
     */
    function putFile($root,$path)
    {
        //TODO still needs implementation
        return $this->put('https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/'.$root.'/'.$path.'?param=val');
    }


    /**
     * test() 
     * test the dropbox upload function
     * @link    https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#files-GET
     * @author  Sean Thomas Burke <http://www.seantburke.com>
     *
     * @param   $root either "sandbox" or "dropbox" $path {url path to document}
     * @return  boolean of 3 required variables (uid is not required, but it helps)
     */
    function test($root)
    {
        $url = 'https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/'.$root.'/test2.txt?overwrite=true&locale=en';
        $body = file_get_contents('test.txt');
        //echo "file_contents: ".$body;
        $fp = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:256000', 'w');
        if (!$fp) {
            die('could not open temp memory data');
        }
        fwrite($fp, $body);
        fseek($fp, 0); 

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        $headers = array('Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="'.self::$APP_KEY.'", oauth_token="'.$this->oauth_access_token.'", oauth_signature="'.$this->oauth_signature.'"');  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
        //echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp); // file pointer
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($body));  

        return $api_response = curl_exec($ch);
    }

}
```

Comment: How about using the [Dropbox SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/php) built by Dropbox itself? They also have a [tutorial available](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php) that does exactly what you are asking for: Listing directories and files, and uploading files.

Answer (score -2):

Here's what works for me. To retrieve a file for which you have a dropbox link, I execute the linux wget command using the dropbox link to your desired file:

```
$filename = "MyLocalFile.txt";  
$get_filename = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1b2c3d4e5f6/myfile.txt';   
$wget_command = 'wget $get_filename --continue=off -O ' . $filename;  
exec($wget_command);
```

And to check to see if it was successful, I just check the filesize of `$filename`.

Comment: The question is specifically on how to accomplish this using the dropbox PHP api. You're just calling the public URLs. Some files might be private and hence not have such URLs